# R cannot be resolved to a variable[ was not able to solve with the solutions given in forums]

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an android project from past one month. I am running the sdk in 64-bit windows 8 pc. I keep encountering the error which states that " R cannot be resolved to a variable". I have tried several solutions which have been posted in the web, some of them are:

- Cleaning the project and building again.
- Removing errors from XML file ( no such error is observed in my project)
- Change of the package name ( which was not at all done in my case)
- Import android.R ( this is not imported in my project)
- Installing latest updates in sdk (all are installed)

This error occurs mostly when I clean the project or build it. The project that i was working on was running till yesterday till I cleaned the project. Building the project is also not solving the problem. In the mean while I was testing code of passing values from android to php to store data in mysql. This was a test code which I had acquired from a website. This code is also showing the same error.

The due date for my project is nearing and I dont know how to solve this error.

Code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sdvd;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String name;
    String id;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    int code;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //final EditText eid=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
        final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
        final EditText e_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Yo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                id = e_id.getText().toString();
                name = e_name.getText().toString();

                insert();
            }
        });
    }

    public void insert()
    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:hint="Id"
     android:padding="11dp" 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
     android:ems="10" 
     android:inputType="number">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="11dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
     android:text="Insert" />
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/editText2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
     android:ems="10" 
     android:hint="Name" 
     android:inputType="textPersonName" 
     android:padding="11dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 package="com.example.sdvd"
 android:versionCode="1" 
 android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application 
     android:allowBackup="true" 
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity 
         android:name="com.example.sdvd.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Cleaning the project often reveals errors hidden in xml files. Double check them ALL, including strings, dimens, drawables, menus, preferences, ... not only layouts. Often there is a SMALL error that doesn't allow R to compile.

Comment: Did you already check all the filenames in the /res folder?

Comment: @mr.boyfox : **"you need import com.example.sdvd.R"** - No. You don't have to import the R class of your own project - it is done implicitly.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Checked my project's strings,dimens, drawables, menus and stuff. No error was found in those files.

Comment: @donfuxx File names as in?? I haven't changed any of the file names in /res folder since the project was created.

Comment: Should I check the build Automatically option? I usually build the project manually before running it.

Comment: @ganapathy It could have been that you copied for example an image file "my-image.jpg" this could cause this problem as well. because `-` is invalid char in android filenames and Eclipse will refuse to regenerate R file because of this

Comment: @donfuxx I checked the file names. None of them contain '-' or any other character that Eclipse doesn't recognise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In activity_main.xml delete the following two lines from your first `EditText`...

```
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Then change the last line of it to have a closing `/` as follows...

```
android:inputType="number" />
```

...then clean / rebuild your project.

**EDIT:** OK, wait...the R.java file you show  in your answer has a package name as follows...

```
package com.example.test;
```

...but the package name of your `Activity` is...

```
package com.example.sdvd;
```

...your `Activity` is never going to find the R.java file in that case as the two have to be in the same package or you have to explicitly import `com.example.test.R` in your `Activity`.

Sort out your package names and get them in line with each other and everything should work.

BTW - for reference here on stackoverflow don't post an answer to your own question which doesn't actually answer the problem - it confuses the situation and makes it harder for people to follow what you're asking - just edit your original question if you need to add extra information.

Comment: Made the changes as suggested by you but still giving the same error after clean/rebuild.

Comment: Sorry!!! I am new to stack overflow . I will follow the protocol from next time.

Actually as I had mentioned in my answer, I was working on package com.example.sdvd. But I created a new project and copied the entire thing from the previous project to the new one. The package of the new one is named com.example.test;
After I changed the project , I dont know how but the R.java file is getting generated... The problem now I am facing is that is 'e1 cannot be resolved or is not a field'. So I checked the R file of new project the editText is not getting added automatically in id section

Comment: So my question is 1) do i have to copy the whole project again if the R file is not getting generated again?

Comment: To answer 1 - No. The R.java file is auto-generated and if you mess with it things can go really screwy (everything in the /gen directory is auto-generated and you shouldn't manually edit them). To answer 2 - if R.java isn't being auto-generated / refreshed then something is clearly wrong - I'm afraid I don't know what it might be. Tips - enable "Build automatically", make sure all classes are in the same package, don't explicitly import R (especially android.R - never do that), clean the project if errors are found, check package explorer for red Xs, use Console to check for general errors.

Comment: This is a problem that I have been facing for a long time. Is this a bug of Eclipse? Is there any better IDE than Eclipse?

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for Android development for 3 years now and  yeah, it can be buggy but I've never had consistent problems. My current app has 11 packages, 82 Java class files and 54 XML layout files - at a rough guess around 12,000 lines of Java / XML. As a last resort, copy your project out and completely delete the Android SDK, ADT and Eclipse and start again from scratch (importing your project into the new setup). There's always Google's Android Studio but I can't vouch for it. I tried an early preview version and it trashed my project - it's supposed to be better now though.

Answer (score 0):

This method solved the R file problem. I just copied the code into a new project . I didn't change anything. The 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' error disappeared magically after I build the project. This method has worked for me a lot of times. But don't you guys think it is a waste of time to copy everything into a new project every time this error occurs ( what if the project is really big). Shouldn't there be a proper solution. How can the code if just copied from one file to another project remove such error.

Although the R file error was removed. A new error is being shown i.e. 'e1 cannot be resolved or is not a field' where e1 is a edittext field which is present in the XML file.

```
<EditText 
     android:id="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:hint="Id"
     android:padding="11dp" 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
     android:ems="10" 
     android:inputType="number"/>
```

I am using the following code to find e1

```
final EditText e_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
```

My R File

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.example.test;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class dimen {
        /**  Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. 

         Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
         screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.

         */
        public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f040000;
        public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f040001;
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f080001;
        public static final int button1=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int main=0x7f070000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f050001;
        public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
        public static final int hello_world=0x7f050002;
    }
    public static final class style {
        /** 
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.

 API 11 theme customizations can go here. 

        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.

 API 14 theme customizations can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f060000;
        /**  Application theme. 
 All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f060001;
    }
}
```

Last time the same error occurred and i cleaned the project. From that moment the R file error was shown. Is there a proper way to debug this error?

Just noticed that my Edit Text is not getting added automatically in the id section of R File

Comment: I was able to access the button in the xml file. But I am not able to access the edit text field.

Comment: In the layout file try changing the `android:layout_alignLeft` and `android:layout_below` attributes to use `@id/e1` instead of `@+id/e1`

Comment: @Squonk I made the changes suggested by you. Still the same error is being shown.

Comment: Just noticed that my Edit Text is not getting added automatically in the id section of R File. Do we have to add it manually?

Comment: Actually not only EditText but none of the components which when added in XML are getting added in the R.java file

Comment: **"Do we have to add it manually?"** - No and don't try editing the R.java file - if you do that will really mess things up. The use of `+` in `@+id/...` is what causes a new id to be added to R.java automatically. Without the `+` in layouts will simply attempt to find ids that have already been added with `@+id/...`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with ending EditText in your xml file.

Try this out..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:hint="Id"
     android:padding="11dp" 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
     android:ems="10" 
     android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="11dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
     android:text="Insert" />
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/editText2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/e1" 
     android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
     android:ems="10" 
     android:hint="Name" 
     android:inputType="textPersonName" 
     android:padding="11dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Made the changes you suggested but still not solving the error.

Comment: Can you just change final EditText e_id to EditText e_id? remove final from your java file?

Comment: Removed the final keyword. Still the same error.
Code:
EditText eid1= findViewById(R.id.e1);                 id=eid1.getText().toString();